# count number of rows different table database

Tags: mysql, sql, count

how can I find the count of number of rows of different tables.i.e

i am using mysql server and i want to have a total count of rows in both the tables

This is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student_it;

  UNION ALL

 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student_cs;

SUM(COUNT(*));
```

Comment: What exactly you want ? Count of All Tables in your Database or Just Few Tables . Which Database are you using ?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Try removing  semi colon after `student_it` and remove `SUM(COUNT(*));` and then run the query with UNION

Comment: i am using mysql server and i want to have a total count of rows in both the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try the following sql:

```
SELECT SUM(tot) FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) tot FROM `student_it` 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT COUNT(*) tot FROM `student_cs`
) sub
```

But I think you should consider storing all students in one `student` table.

Comment: it's an alias for the subquery. you need to do that in mysql (if i'm not mistaken) or you'll get a `Every derived table must have its own alias` error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_msforeachtable` like this:

```
Use <your_db>;
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable N'select count(*) from ?;';
```

Also if you need to filter the data you can use the `@whereand` paremeter.

Answer (score 0):

Add the table names in the `WHERE` clause and execute the below query:

```
SELECT 
    T.Name AS TableName,
    S.Row_count AS RecordsCount
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats S
INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON T.object_id = S.object_id
Where 
    Object_Name(S.Object_Id) IN ('Employees','Country')
```

**Note:** `Employees, Country` are Table Names.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this....

```
SELECT SUM (abc)
FROM   (SELECT COUNT (*) abc
    FROM   student_it
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT (*)
    FROM   student_cs)
```